# Curiosity on theorem about generating sets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Thm. (Fraleigh, 7.6)

> If G is a group and $a_i$ $\in$G for $i \in I$,then the subgroup H of G generated by {$a_i |\  i \in I$} has as elements precisely those elements of G that are **finite** products of integral powers of the $a_i$, where powers of a fixed $a_i$ may occur several times in the product.

I'm curious about why it should be finite products.

Let G= $\Bbb Z$ and H is generated by $a_1$=3, $a_2$=5

(operation is usual addition.)

then it seems like infinite products of integral powers of the $a_i$ works.

Why it should be finite products?

Comment: Note that it really means integral powers, where  integers may be negative.

Comment: And what element of $G$ would that infinite product be? For instance, what is $3\cdot 5 \cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot \ldots$? (note: in this case $\cdot$ is our normal addition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because infinite products are meaningless (undefined). *Finite* products may be defined inductively: for instance, $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$ may be computed by first computing $a_1a_2$, then right-multiplying this by $a_3$, and so on, until you right-multiply by $a_n$. Associativity guarantees that this is well-defined.

But on the other hand, if infinite products were allowed, your $H$ should contain $$3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + \cdots$$

which is evidently not a well-defined integer.

Comment: Maybe not in my case, but what if there is a instance? Then how can i be sure

Comment: @JAEMTO Given the limited axioms imposed on a group, it is impossible to give a well-defined meaning to an expression like $a^\infty$ that should represent an "infinite product" and be consistent with the group arithmetic. For instance, one would certainly hope that $a\cdot a^\infty = a^\infty$, but this would imply that $a =$ identity by right-cancellation.

Comment: Ohhhh really thx now I fully understand

Comment: The idea of the finitely generated subgroup is that it's the smallest set containing the generators that also satisfies the group axioms. Since the relevant axiom (closure under the BINARY operation) only demands products of two elements, then we only need finite products.